# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext .NET 6 without OnConfiguring

Tags: .net, entity-framework, migration, .net-6.0

When I use the command to add the migration, I get two errors:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

This when I don't initialize an empty constructor for `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Pessoas>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options) { }
    
    public DbSet<Pessoas> Pessoas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Creditos> Creditos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Debitos> Debitos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Ignore<Notification>();
        builder.Entity<Pessoas>().ToTable(nameof(Pessoas)).HasKey(p => p.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder.Properties<String>()
            .HaveMaxLength(100);
        configurationBuilder.Properties<int>()
            .HaveMaxLength(4);
        base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);
    }

}
```

If I initialize an empty constructor, I get a different error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

For this code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<Pessoas>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options) { }
    
    public DbSet<Pessoas> Pessoas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Creditos> Creditos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Debitos> Debitos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Ignore<Notification>();
        builder.Entity<Pessoas>().ToTable(nameof(Pessoas)).HasKey(p => p.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
    {
        configurationBuilder.Properties<String>()
            .HaveMaxLength(100);
        configurationBuilder.Properties<int>()
            .HaveMaxLength(4);
        base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);
    }

}
```

This is my `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration["ConnectionString:Connection"])
);
builder.Services.AddIdentity<Pessoas, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPessoas, PessoasRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPessoasApplication, PessoasService>();
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

It only works if I overwrite the `OnConfiguring` in the `DbContext` and make my connection string explicit. However, I don't like working with this approach and in the video I saw for example, it worked without `OnConfiguring`, using the connection string only in `Program.cs`. I cloned this example project and trying to run migrations on it, the same error as my code is presented.
My friend cloned this same example project and trying to run migrations on it, and have success.

I tried several solutions and I would like it to work without having to overwrite `OnConfiguring`

Comment: Im able to run migrations with this, what's in your `appsettings.json`?

Comment: I was only able to use it via nuget pack and informing the context.
Add-Migration -db ApplicationDbContext